# Question about error in solution for Leetcode 217: Contains Duplicate (Java), using ArrayList

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm a beginner coder in Java trying to hone my technical skills on leetcode. Here's the [link](https://leetcode.com/problems/contains-duplicate/description/) to the question I'm working on.

Here's my solution in Java:

```
class Solution {
    public boolean containsDuplicate(int[] nums) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arr = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            if (arr.contains(nums[i])) {
                return true;
            } else {
                arr.add(nums[i]);
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I can't seem to pass the 65th test case. The error returned was "Time Limit Exceeded". Can someone explain to me what's wrong with my logic? Is there some kind of edge case I'm missing?

(Edit: thank you for all the answers! I will work on learning time complexities as most have suggested :))

Comment: Your logic is fine, it's just too slow. Find a faster way.

Comment: This question needs details or clarity.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, the problem here is the speed. Using a `HashSet` instead of an `ArrayList` would provide an O(1) `contains` operation, and should do the trick.

Answer (score -2):

These types of questions are typically intended to test your knowledge of data structures, algorithms, and runtime complexity. You should [learn](https://techdevguide.withgoogle.com/paths/data-structures-and-algorithms/) about these things. Using the correct data structure can significantly decrease the runtime complexity of any algorithm.

For this particular problem, you can use a data structure backed by a [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) implementation, which would provide a find operation of `O(1)`.

As has already been mentioned, you can achieve this by using a [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) instead of `ArrayList`.